# Batch File That Keeps Other Batch Files Running

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch, batch-file, script

I run 3 .bat files on my computer at all times 24/7 for a business that I have. Every now and then they will close because of my internet drops due to the area I live in and they need internet to run.

Is there a way that I can have a batch file that opens the other 3 files and checks to make sure if one has closed, if so, it opens it again? Maybe have it do a check every x amount of minutes

The batch files names are:

```
vfile1.bat

vfile2.bat

vfile3.bat
```

So basically I want open a file like group.bat and it will open the 3 in the list above and reopen them if they close.

I tried to look online for this solution but I don't know what to search for.

Comment: I guess you could use tasklist to check if they are running and if not start them, but why are they closed in the first place? Isn't it easier to just let them running even if there is no internet?

Comment: The tasklist worked. But yeah even if they don't close the script will stop and I have to go start it again. I set it to close so I know when they are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your batch files are called Batch01.bat, Batch02.bat and Batch03.bat and have the title of Batch01, Batch02 and Batch03. You can set this in a Batch with ex: Title Batch01

Could look something like this:

```
@echo off
Title Keep Running Batchs
set Batch01Path=%userprofile%\desktop\Batch01.bat
set Batch02Path=%userprofile%\desktop\Batch02.bat
set Batch03Path=%userprofile%\desktop\Batch03.bat

:Restart
cls
echo.
tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq Batch01" /v /fo csv |find /i "Batch01" > Nul
if "%errorlevel%"=="0" (Echo  Batch01.bat Running OK) else (Echo  Batch01.bat Closed ...Restarting& start "" "%Batch01Path%") 
tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq  Batch02" /v /fo csv |find /i "Batch02" > Nul
if "%errorlevel%"=="0" (Echo  Batch02.bat Running OK) else (Echo  Batch02.bat Closed ...Restarting& start "" "%Batch02Path%")
tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq Batch03" /v /fo csv |find /i "Batch03" > Nul
if "%errorlevel%"=="0" (Echo  Batch03.bat Running OK) else (Echo  Batch03.bat Closed ...Restarting& start "" "%Batch03Path%")
timeout /t 5 >nul
goto :Restart
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This worked! Make sure to set the title for each batch file for anyone who uses this

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Edit your `file.bat` and add the names to the title of each file:

```bat
title <nul && title vfile1.bat 
title <nul && title vfile2.bat 
title <nul && title vfile3.bat

rem :: Or add this line to each bat file :: 
title <nul && title %~n0
```

**2.** Use `for` loop, `:label` and `operator` to check if need re-start each one

```bat
@echo off  

title <nul && title %~n0

:loop
for %%i in ("vfile1","vfile2","vfile3")do (
     %__AppDir__%tasklist.exe /FI "windowtitle eq %%~i" >nul || start "" /b "%%i.bat"
    )
  
%__AppDir__%timeout.exe /t 6000 & goto :loop
```

---

Read more:

- **[For](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**
- **[Start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)**
- **[Title](https://ss64.com/nt/title.html)**
- **[Tasklist](https://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html)**
- **[Timeout](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)**
- **[Goto :Label](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)**
- **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

Comment: Thank you! This works as well